# Finding the shortest distance between two points Python

Tags: python, pandas, distance, haversine

I have two dataframe. One contains `properties locations`, and the other contains `railway stations locations`.

sample of properties dataframe(original Dataframe consist of ~700 rows):

```
properties=pd.DataFrame({'propertyID':['13425','32535','43255','52521'],
                 'lat':[-37.79230,-37.86400,-37.85450,-37.71870],
                'lon':[145.10290,145.09720,145.02190,144.94330]})
```

sample of railway station dataframe(original Dataframe consist of ~90 rows):

```
stations=pd.DataFrame({'stationID':['11','33','21','34','22'],
                 'lat':[-37.416861,-37.703293,-37.729261,-37.777764,-37.579206],
                'lon':[145.005372,144.572524,144.650631,144.772304,144.728165]})
```

I have a function to calculate the distance between two locations

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6378 # Radius of earth in kilometers
    return c * r
```

I want to find the distance between each property and all stations. Then then pick the station with the shortest distance.

I tried to construct a for loop but it doesn't return the shortest distance (min)

```
lst=[]
for stopLat in stations['lat']:
    for stopLon in stations['lon']:
        for propLat in properties['lat']:
            for propLon in properties['lon']:
                lst.append(haversine(propLon,propLat,stopLon,stopLat))
```

My final output would look like this. (Each property linked to the closest station).

```
stationID propertyID 
11        52521
33        13425
21        32535
34        43255
```

Any advice on how to approach this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you refering to shortest path like graph Djikstra, I think it's easie to do it with networkx?

Comment: [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree) in Sklearn supports the [haversine](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) distance.  So you could create a BallTree using the properties.  Then find the minimum distance to each station to a point in the BallTree (i.e. nearest neighbor).  This should be fast and efficient (since Sklearn algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its kind of a workaround but I first merge both dataframes with an additional 'key'.
Then I use apply to calculate the distance:

```
properties['key'] = 1
stations['key'] = 1

df = properties.merge(stations,on='key')
del df['key']
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: haversine(x['lon_x'],x['lat_x'],x['lon_y'],x['lat_y']),axis=1)
print(df)
df = df.loc[df.groupby("propertyID")["distance"].idxmin()]
df = df[['stationID','propertyID']]
print(df)
```

First print:

```
   propertyID    lat_x     lon_x stationID      lat_y       lon_y   distance
0       13425 -37.7923  145.1029        11 -37.416861  145.005372  42.668639
1       13425 -37.7923  145.1029        33 -37.703293  144.572524  47.723406
2       13425 -37.7923  145.1029        21 -37.729261  144.650631  40.415507
3       13425 -37.7923  145.1029        34 -37.777764  144.772304  29.129338
4       13425 -37.7923  145.1029        22 -37.579206  144.728165  40.650436
5       32535 -37.8640  145.0972        11 -37.416861  145.005372  50.428078
6       32535 -37.8640  145.0972        33 -37.703293  144.572524  49.504807
7       32535 -37.8640  145.0972        21 -37.729261  144.650631  42.047056
8       32535 -37.8640  145.0972        34 -37.777764  144.772304  30.138684
9       32535 -37.8640  145.0972        22 -37.579206  144.728165  45.397047
10      43255 -37.8545  145.0219        11 -37.416861  145.005372  48.738487
11      43255 -37.8545  145.0219        33 -37.703293  144.572524  42.971083
12      43255 -37.8545  145.0219        21 -37.729261  144.650631  35.510616
13      43255 -37.8545  145.0219        34 -37.777764  144.772304  23.552690
14      43255 -37.8545  145.0219        22 -37.579206  144.728165  40.101407
15      52521 -37.7187  144.9433        11 -37.416861  145.005372  34.043280
16      52521 -37.7187  144.9433        33 -37.703293  144.572524  32.696875
17      52521 -37.7187  144.9433        21 -37.729261  144.650631  25.795774
18      52521 -37.7187  144.9433        34 -37.777764  144.772304  16.424364
19      52521 -37.7187  144.9433        22 -37.579206  144.728165  24.508280
```

Second print:

```
   stationID propertyID
3         34      13425
8         34      32535
13        34      43255
18        34      52521
```

But according to this output station 34 is always the closest. Is that correct?

**EDIT: Further explanation:**

I once tried to find a way to "merge" two dataframes together that have no common unique identifier that is usually used for merging.

I also wanted to pair each row of one dataframe with the other dataframe (in your case each station with each property) to be able to compare those entries. 
In my research I found this clever workaround to use a dummy key.

A merge usually combines dataframe based on a unique identifier but only those rows that match. So dataframe A "ID" = 1 only matches with those who have "ID" = 1 in dataframe B.(Read here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

In this workaround used we see that the key for every row is 1 so every row will match with every row from the other dataframe doing exactly what we want.

With the apply function you can apply any function to your dataframe going row by row.

Comment: Thank you for this neat solution. It seems to be working. I am going to plot my data to make sure my output is correct. Thank you.

Comment: If it is possible, would you add some clarification regarding your method? How does the merge work? and is each property location compared to all stations locations?

Comment: Thank you mgruber

Answer (score 1):

Using [BallTree from Sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) which provides a faster method for finding nearest neighbors

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree, BallTree

properties=pd.DataFrame({'propertyID':['13425','32535','43255','52521'],
                 'lat':[-37.79230,-37.86400,-37.85450,-37.71870],
                'lon':[145.10290,145.09720,145.02190,144.94330]})

stations=pd.DataFrame({'stationID':['11','33','21','34','22'],
                 'lat':[-37.416861,-37.703293,-37.729261,-37.777764,-37.579206],
                'lon':[145.005372,144.572524,144.650631,144.772304,144.728165]})

property_coords = properties.as_matrix(columns=['lat', 'lon'])
station_coords = stations.as_matrix(columns=['lat', 'lon'])

# Create BallTree using station coordinates and specify distance metric
tree = BallTree(station_coords, metric = 'haversine')

print('PropertyID StationID Distance')
for i, property in enumerate(property_coords):
    dist, ind = tree.query(property.reshape(1, -1), k=1) # distance to first nearest station
    print(properties['propertyID'][i], stations['stationID'][ind[0][0]], dist[0][0], sep ='\t')
```

Output

```
PropertyID StationID Distance
13425   34  0.329682946662
32535   34  0.333699645179
43255   34  0.259425428922
52521   34  0.180690281514
```

**Performance**

Summary--BallTree > 5x faster than method of merging dataframees

*Details (assume preload libraries and data)*

Method 1--Using BallTree

```
%%timeit

property_coords = properties.as_matrix(columns=['lat', 'lon'])
station_coords = stations.as_matrix(columns=['lat', 'lon'])

# Create BallTree using station coordinates and specify distance metric
tree = BallTree(station_coords, metric = 'haversine')

for i, property in enumerate(property_coords):
    dist, ind = tree.query(property.reshape(1, -1), k=1) # distance to first nearest station

100 loops, best of 3: 1.79 ms per loop
```

Method 2--merge both dataframes

```
%%timeit

properties['key'] = 1
stations['key'] = 1

df = properties.merge(stations,on='key')
del df['key']
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: haversine(x['lon_x'],x['lat_x'],x['lon_y'],x['lat_y']),axis=1)
#print(df)
df = df.loc[df.groupby("propertyID")["distance"].idxmin()]
df = df[['stationID','propertyID']]

100 loops, best of 3: 10 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you DarrylG. I tried the k-nearest neighbour method. For some reason it returns the first 6 observation then returns error. `KeyError: 78`. The second method works. Thanks again.

Comment: @leena--are you trying the exact same code as above or a modification?

Comment: @leena--here's a [link to code](https://repl.it/repls/JitteryCarelessConstants) I tried (note: you can ignore the warning about as_matrix will be removed in a future version for now).

Comment: Thank you DarrylG